# Javascript help for target attribute

Tags: javascript

I have a smaller new window instead of opening a new tab from download a pdf.
I want only callback variable from downlado.jsp i.e. when its working is done on parent window  to close downlado.jsp .from where i have invoked send me function.

JavaScript:

```
function sendme()
{
    winname = "myNewWin";
    window.open("","myNewWin","width=500,height=300,toolbar=0");
    lsurl  = "downlado.jsp";
    window.document.Form.action = lsurl;
    window.document.Form.target = winName;
    window.document.Form.submit();
    window.setTimeout("window.close",5000);
 }
```

For example

```
function callback()
{
    close download jsp;
}
```

Comment: Im not sure I understand. You want to close the new window when the download finishes?

Comment: yes. u have understood correct. But if before download finish if new window closes then save dialog for pdf is also not came. i want variable from new window which tells me that download finish and then i'll call close to new window.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately impossible in pure Javascript. However, you could use a following workaround:

- Start the download in new window
- Periodically make an AJAX call to the server to check if the download finished.
- If yes, close the window.

OK, as for the AJAX part, you will need to know two things:

1. How to make AJAX calls - this is pretty straightforward and there is lots of examples on the web. If you are unfamiliar with AJAX I recommend you use [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).
2. You need information from your HTTP server to tell you when has file finished downloading. Assuming you use Apache, then [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/53454/130910) about conditional logging may give you some idea where to look (although instead of deleting the file you would probably want to create a new file somewhere that you can make the AJAX call to - and determine if the file finished downloading).

Comment: i know AJAX call and i can do it but can u please elaborate some step by code that i can easily understand....jus simply make two calls one to ajax and one two genrate pdf..

Comment: Here is a thought for a much simpler solution.... Why don't you just close the window straight away after the download starts? Why does the window need to remain open while downloading? If you close it straight away the file will still download fine.

Comment: First i'm making call to method to genrate pdf from new window.in that jsp i have used response.adheader("Content-Disposition","attachment:filename="+filename); so if window closed i didn't get save dialog. Second i dont want allow user to navigate any where else before his download is finish for that i have bolced ui. from callback variable i'll refresh the screen and unlock the UI.